# openCV imshow not rendering image on screen

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am new to openCV, have recently obtained a pre-compiled version of openCV 2.4.7 and was successfully able to integrate it with visual studio 2010.

Apparently library seems to work fine, but when I'm trying to display image using imshow it displays the window but doesn't display image in it.

```
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("F:/office_Renzym/test3.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

    if(image.empty())
    {
        cout<<"image not loaded";
    }
    else
    {
        cv::namedWindow( "test", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        cv::imshow("test",image);
    }   
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a call to [waitKey](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) after `imshow`?

Comment: I would have included image with the question but as i have recently got myself registered here, so i can not include images yet

Comment: yes have tried waitKey still no success

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You must have:

```
cv::waitKey(0);
```

instead of:

```
system("pause");
```

The latter just doesn't work. OpenCV needs to pump messages to get the window displayed and updated, and inside that `waitKey` function is all of the mechanism to do so.

As the documentation says, `waitKey` only works if you have a HighGUI window open, so in your code, you probably need to do this:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("F:/office_Renzym/test3.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

if(image.empty())
{
    cout<<"image not loaded";
}
else
{
    cv::namedWindow( "test", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cv::imshow("test",image);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

In case there's a problem with the image format, you might try loading like this:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("F:/office_Renzym/test3.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest removing the `cv::namedWindow` statement, and adding

```
cv::waitKey();
```

after the `cv:imshow` statement. You can also check whether the dimensions of the window are correct.

Comment: From the above answer, the problem seems to have been in the image format.

Answer (score 2):

For Python users, using `cv2.wait(0)` is the solution. So, the overall format goes like this

```
    cv2.imwrite("DetectionResults.jpg", frame)
    cv2.imshow("DetectionResults", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cv2.waitKey(0)` waits for key-press indefinitely. In case of streamed data where update is required, better use `cv2.pollKey()` instead of (often suggested) `cv2.waitKey(1)`, which actually introduces at least 1 ms delay.